# Given the monotone decreasing function and a point $a\in\mathbb{R}$ prove that f is continuous in a.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, monotone-functions

Given the monotone decreasing function and a point $a\in\mathbb{R}$, given is that $\forall \epsilon \exists p<a,q>a$ so that $f(p)-f(q)<\epsilon$ prove that f is continuous in a.

where do I go from here?

Comment: How did you get $f(p)-f(q)\leq f(p)-f(p)$?

Comment: for any $ p<q$ $f(q)\le f(p)$ because it is monotone decreasing (not sure if it is the right word though)

Comment: But that means that $-f(q)\geq -f(p)$. Now add $f(p)$ to both sides, and see what you get.

Comment: $f(q)\le f(p)$ would imply $-f(q)\ge f(p)$ and hence $f(p)-f(q)\ge f(p)-f(p)$.

Comment: oh right, my bad, now i am even more stuck

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon >0$. Then let $p_\epsilon$ and $q_\epsilon$ be the points guaranteed by your given condition. Let $\delta=\min\{a-p_\epsilon,q_\epsilon-a\}$. Then we have:

$|x-a|<\delta \implies p_\epsilon\leq x\leq a$ or $a\leq x\leq q_\epsilon$.

In either case, can you show that $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$?

Comment: Can i do this because we know that $|f(x)-f(a)| \le |f(q)-f(a)| \le |f(q)-f(p)| <\epsilon$?

Comment: Close. We know that both $x$ and $a$ are between $p$ and $q$, but it's not certain in which order. In either case, $|f(x)-f(a)| \leq |f(q)-f(p)|$ because of the function's monotonicity. I'm not sure you can get that middle step inequality you wrote, but you can get by without it. Perhaps $p<x<a<q$, with $f(q)-f(a)$ being the smallest gap.

Comment: A right, but the proof is now done right? (When you write it down properly ofc) because with that information you can say that that is true $\forall p<x<q$ and for every $\epsilon$ there is a p and q.

Comment: What you need to say is that, for every $\epsilon$, there is a $\delta$. We have established that. The points $p_\epsilon$ and $q_\epsilon$ are just intermediaries to help you find the appropriate $\delta$.